# Angular Reusable dialog component with different components injected

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog, modal-dialog

I have an app with 10+ different dialogs. Inside each dialog I am injecting different component. My code works fine, but I have a lot of dialog configuration that I am repeating, like all the dialogs have the same buttons and same way of managing the cancelation actions. Also in all of them, I have the some variables that are the same.
I would love ideally to do this:
Create my dialog dialog component with my custom configuration, buttons and cancel actions and inside this dialog every time injects different component.
So instead this:

```
 this.dialog.open(componentThatIwantToInject, {
  data: myData,
  disableClose: true,
  hasBackdrop: true
})
```

have something like this

```
dialog.openById(idOfDialogToOpen, componentIwantToInject), {
  data: myData,
  disableClose: true,
  hasBackdrop: true
})
```

I have read this article - https://zoaibkhan.com/blog/create-reusable-confirmation-dialogs-with-angular-material/ doesn't work as I need to pass the whole component not only data,
I have also looked into getDialogById() in Angular documentation https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api but I can't figure it out how to assign the id to my dialog component to always open the same one.
Is there any way to do this with Angular or ?
Thank you!

Comment: I assume myData can change every time right? The other 2 attributes you can probably set globally depending on the dialog you’re using..

Comment: No Actually, as the component I want to inject always changes too... But thank you for your comment.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to write a generic service that just takes a component as parameter and the service then uses MatDialog to instantiate the component in a dialog. But lots of injection null errors :(

Comment: @Spock no sorry I didn't, I continued with the old approach sorry